# TCPclient stuck on read when I try to retrieve a file on the server

Tags: c#, tcp

I make a program to send a file to another computer for video encoding. File sends work. But when I uncomment function "Download" of the server to retrieve a file to the server, the client gets stuck at read (client "Download" function).

Client :

```
static byte[] DownloadHASH(NetworkStream stream)
{

        byte[] check = new byte[32];

        stream.Read(check, 0, 32);
        return check;
}


static string Download(NetworkStream stream)
{
        int recByte = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        string tempFile = string.Format(@"{0}.mkv", Guid.NewGuid());
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        Guid.NewGuid();

        while ((recByte = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            fstream.Write(buffer, 0, recByte);

        }
        fstream.Close();
        return tempFile;
 }

 static void UpLoad(NetworkStream stream, string file) {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int sendBytes = 0;
        int offset = 0;
        while ((sendBytes = fs.Read(bytes, offset, bytes.Length)) > 0)
        {

            stream.Write(bytes, 0, sendBytes);
        }
  }
```

Server:

```
  FileStream fs = new FileStream(currentOp.file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  stream.Write(currentOp.checksum, 0 , currentOp.checksum.Length);
  byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
  int sendBytes = 0;
  int offset = 0;
  while ((sendBytes = fs.Read(bytes, offset, bytes.Length)) > 0)
  {

      stream.Write(bytes, 0, sendBytes);
  }
  fs.Close();
  //Download(stream);

  void Download(NetworkStream stream)
  {
        int recByte = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        string tempFile = string.Format(@"{0}.mp4", Guid.NewGuid());
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream(tempFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        Guid.NewGuid();

        while ((recByte = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            fstream.Read(buffer, 0, recByte);
        }
        fstream.Close();
   }
```

I don't know why this append. Someone can help me?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Where is the code where you are invoking these operations? You are obviously waiting for data on the client, that is never sent by the server, but why, we can't see yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program reads data from the stream until it reads 0 bytes:

```
while ((recByte = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
```

However `NetworkStream` only returns 0 when the other side closes the connection. You have two options to fix this:

- Close the stream on the other side after all data has been sent, or
- Wrap the data in a message format, for instance first send the size of the data as a fixed-size message, followed by exactly that many bytes, so your client knows when it has completed downloading the file